# How to match only extensionless URLs?

Tags: asp.net, regex, url

I want a regex expression which only match extensionless url. In otherwords if an extension is present in url then completely ignore it.

`/(.+)/(.+)` this will match an URL both with and without extension.

www.site.com/sports/cricket  should match

www.site.com/sports/cricket.aspx shouldn't match

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about www.site.com/sports.aspx/cricket? And "/(.+)/(.+)" does not match www.site.com. Is this intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will only match strings which have at least two `/` (per your example regex), and don't have a `.` anywhere after the last `/`:

```
/(.+)/([^\./]+)$
```

I'd recommend http://www.regular-expressions.info/ if you want to learn more about regexs.

Answer (score 2):

```
.+/[^./]*$
```

This will match strings with no . after last /

Answer (score 0):

```
^/(.+)/([^/.]*)$
```

will match a URL (without a domain) that contains no dot after the last slash.

EDIT: Adapted it better to the original regex.

Comment: you need to escape . in [^/.], so [^\.] may be?

Comment: No you don't. The dot is a literal dot inside character classes.