# Redirecting dynamic extensionless urls using urlrewrite wildcards

Tags: asp.net, regex, iis-7, url-rewriting, wildcard-mapping

I have a dynamic list of "referrers", example ANN, BOB, ..., ZED. I want people who go to my url www.website.com/ANN, www.website.com/BOB, www.website.com/ZED to be directed to a special dynamically generated referrer page.

What I want to do is set up a [URLRewriter rule](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/465/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference/) on my IIS7 that will direct any page without a file extension to a /reroute.aspx which will handle generating the dynamic page. What I'm having a problem with is the regular or wildcard expression. I've tried

```
/*.*
*.*
/([^/.]*)
```

The first two will work with /ANN  if I use the "Does not match" setting, but then they also work on www.website.com/ which is the default address. The third one, [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514820/how-to-match-only-extensionless-urls), doesn't match /ANN  according to the IIS expression checker.

I'd appreciate any advice any regex wizards could provide. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I just gave up trying to use such a simple link, and am using www.website.com/Refer/ANN

The Query string I am using is
    refer/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$

And Olivier was right, the $ is important :)

Comment: I also want to add that I've found a more elegant solution since. I use an IRouteHandler custom class with definitions in the Global.asax function void RegisterRoutes. If anyone comes across this looking for information and wants me to elaborate, just let me know.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** I just thought of something... maybe the leading `/` shouldn't be there.  You could try this:

```
([^/.]*)$
```

I'm also thinking, to pass querystrings through, you could possibly do this:

```
([^/.?]*)(\?.*)?$
```

...and use `{C:2}` in the replacement string to copy over the querystring.

---

The `$` is important:

```
/([^/.]*)$
```

Then again, maybe not... it's really just a guess.

Comment: I tried it with and without, so I think the problem lies elsewhere. I also realized that this whole idea is going to cause problems with any querystring-utilizing links I might use. What a headache.

Comment: For the querystring issue, you could simply add `?` in `[^/.?]`, as long as you always escape `/` inside the querystring.  But yeah, this should be working... odd.