# regex match extensionless url with or without query parameter

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match extension-less url with or without query parameter.
So far `.+\/[^.\/]*$` matches some of them but it fails when `.` is present in query parameters

For example what i want is

```
http://www.example.com/ -> MATCH
http://www.example.com/abc -> MATCH
http://www.example.com/abc/def/ -> MATCH
http://www.example.com/abc/def.ext/ -> MATCH
http://www.example.com/abc?param=abc.def -> MATCH
http://www.anything.com/abc/def.ext/?param=abc.ext -> MATCH

http://www.example.com/abc.ext -> DONT MATCH
http://www.example.com/abc/def.ext -> DONT MATCH
http://www.anything.com/abc/def.ext?param=abc -> DONT MATCH
http://www.anything.com/abc/def.ext?param=abc.def -> DONT MATCH
```

The answers provided in [How to match only extensionless URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514820/how-to-match-only-extensionless-urls) fails when `.` or `/` are present in query parameters key or value. I've tried with many patterns but couldn't get desired result.

I am noob in regex. Please help.

Comment: What language/tool are you using? What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?

Comment: @Toto, In my case i was trying in js. are not regular expressions are common to most of the languages, e.g. js, java, php.?

Comment: No, they are not. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/372239 and https://www.regular-expressions.info/tools.html

Comment: Few of my expressions was .+\/[^.\/]*$, .+\/[^.\/]*\?.*$, .+\/[^.\/]*(|\?.*)$, .+\/[^.\/]*(|\?.*[^.]*)$

Comment: @Toto Same is written on the stackoverflow link you shared *.. these languages share the same syntax.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Regex: `.+\/[^.\/]*?(?:\?.+)?$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aO5kkB/1)

Comment: That worked, what i was missing in my tries was greedy ? quantifier at last. Thanks a ton.